# Recommendations for a hosted blog with a plugin that allows syntax highlighting.

Tags: cms, blog, plugin

I want to keep a blog with useful code snippets for myself. I don't want to setup some website with blogging software or something similar.

All I want is register with a blog site and be able to use syntax-highlighting. (like wordpress or google blog only with syntax-highlighting)

any links ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://ikiwiki.info has [syntax highlighting](http://ikiwiki.info/todo/syntax_highlighting/) done with [a supported plugin](http://ikiwiki.info/plugins/highlight/);

It also can use one of the popular [DVCS as the backend](http://ikiwiki.info/rcs/), so it must be convenient for you: you'll have your code snippets under version control.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for? Its not necessarily a blog host, but I think it accomplishes what you want. http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: can i plug this into existing blogwebsite like wordpress or google blog ? (e.g. into the skin or so?)

Answer (score 0):

[this article](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/syntax-highlighting-stackoverflow-google-prettify) tells you how it's done. I do not think, however, that any blog comes with it preinstalled. If you don't do a fair bit of web programming i think it would be reasonably hard to get it done.